# Is there a way to have a pivot table dynamically update its formatting based on the formatting of another pivot table?

Tags: excel, formatting, pivot-table

I have a couple of workbooks in which i have separate pivot tables. What I am hoping to do is to be able to have cell formatting applied in pivot #1 to the same data point cell in another table.
For example I have table #1 sorted by account name displaying serial numbers underneath as a sub row. If I apply a cell style to a serial number field there, can I have that serial number show up with the same format in another table that is sorted / displayed differently, say sorted by serial number grouped by count or a different row hierarchy?

Super short, like the question says
Can a cell style applied in one pivot table automatically be applied to a matching cell in another pivot table?

I've tried doing a nested table by setting table 1 as the source for table 2, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: With VBA, possibly, but not sure.

Comment: i figured that would be the likely way to go. Havent coded in much of anything in quite a while  (many years) so ugh. Thanks though. Maybe somebody has an idea.